# enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI

Tags: cors

I am trying to build a project with React for my client side and .NET for my API went i try to make a Post request this comes out
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:xxx/api/Registration/register' from origin 'http://localhost:xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
 public class Program

    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            var _config = builder.Configuration;
           // builder.Services.AddCors();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, StudentRepository>();

            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c=> 
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "User", Version = "v1"  });
            });
           
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>opt.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")) );


            builder.Services.AddCors();
            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseCors(options =>
            {
                options.WithMethods("http://localhost:xxx", "https://localhost:xxx");
            });

         

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
                    

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            // app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
           // app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }

        
    }
}


      fetch('https://localhost:xxx/api/Registration/register',{
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(items),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((items) => {
          console.log('Success:', items);
        })
```

i have try all the resources i have seen but it dose not work can some please helpme

Answer (score 0):

You can use policies for CORS. I hope it helps.

Add services.AddCors(...); BEFORE services.AddMvc(); or services.AddControllers();

```
services.AddCors(options =>
  options.AddPolicy("myclient", builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:XXXX", "http://localhost:XXXX").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));
.
.
.

app.UseCors("myclient");
```